# Pegar dados de um formulário de edição - React

Tags: react

Estou desenvolvendo uma single page onde posso editar os dados de um usuário, mas tive problemas pra desenvolver com Formik, não tive muita alternativa, já que ele é melhor em muitos aspectos. Então tentei usá-lo e consegui carregar os dados do usuário no input do form de edição, porém, os dados que eu tento alterar não são atualizados, pois ele não está pegando os dados do input (tanto dos dados que são carregados no input, como os dados que insiro), então queria saber qual o problema com o meu formulário e a lógica que estou usando.

Obs: Já testei o método put da API que estou consumindo e está funcionando.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Container, CustomInput, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../assets/css/main.css'
import './style.css'
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import api from '../../services/api'


const FormEditar = (props) => {
  const {id} = useParams('');
  const obj = {id: '', nome: '', telefone: '', dtNascimento: '', cpf: '', cnpj: '', categoria: '' };
  const {nome, telefone, dtNascimento, cpf, cnh, categoria} = props.data;
  const initialValues = props.data.id === undefined ? obj : {id, nome, telefone, dtNascimento, cpf, cnh, categoria};
  const enableReinitialize = true;

const history = useHistory();
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues,
  enableReinitialize
});

const DisplayErrors = (props) => {
  const { msgError } = props
  return(
      <>
      {msgError && <span className="validate-error">{msgError}</span>}
      </>    
  )
}

const [sendNome, setNome] = useState('');
const [sendTelefone, setTelefone] = useState('');
const [sendDtNascimento, setDtNascimento] = useState('');
const [sendCpf, setCpf] = useState('');
const [sendCnh, setCnh] = useState('');
const [sendCategoria, setCategoria] = useState([]);
const [motorista, setMotorista] = useState('');

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setNome({ ...sendNome, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  setTelefone({ ...sendTelefone, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  setDtNascimento({ ...sendDtNascimento, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  setCpf({ ...sendCpf, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  setCnh({ ...sendCnh, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  setCategoria({ ...sendCategoria, [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
}

function onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let errors = formik.errors;
  let values = formik.values;

  if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0 || values.email === "" ) {
    alert("Os dados devem ser preenchidos corretamente!");
    return;
  }


    api.put(`motoristas/${id}`, initialValues)
    .then(() => {
        alert(`Dados atualizados com sucesso!`)
        history.push('/');
    }).catch((error) =>  alert("Não foi possível atualizar os dados, tente novamente!"))
}
return (
  <Container id="form-input">
    <h2>Edite seus dados</h2>
    <div id="box-input" >
      <Form method="put" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <FormGroup >
            <Label for="nome">Nome:</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo" 
            for="nome"
            {...formik.getFieldProps("nome")}
            /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.nome}/>}
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="dtNascimento">Data de Nascimento:</Label>
            <Input type="date" name="dtNascimento" id="dtNascimento" placeholder="00/00/0000" 
            onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("dtNascimento")}
            /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.dtNascimento}/>}
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="telefone">Telefone:</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone com DDD" onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("telefone")}
            /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.telefone}/>}
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="cpf">CPF:</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF" 
            onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("cpf")}
            /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.cpf}/>}
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="cnh">CNH:</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="Número da CNH..."  onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("cnh")}
            /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.cnh}/>}
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="categoria" className="categoria">Marque a(as) categoria(as) da sua CNH: </Label>
              <CustomInput type="checkbox" id="exampleCustomCheckbox"  label="A" inline  onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("categoria")}
              /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.categoria}/>}
              <CustomInput type="checkbox" id="exampleCustomCheckbox2" label="B" inline onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("categoria")}
              /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.categoria}/>}
              <CustomInput type="checkbox" id="exampleCustomCheckbox3" label="C"  inline onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("categoria")}
              /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.categoria}/>}
              <CustomInput type="checkbox" id="exampleCustomCheckbox4" label="D" inline onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("categoria")}
              /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.categoria}/>}
              <CustomInput type="checkbox" id="exampleCustomCheckbox5" label="E" inline onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("categoria")}
              /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.categoria}/>}
              <CustomInput type="checkbox" id="exampleCustomCheckbox6" label="AAC" inline onChange={formik.handleChange} {...formik.getFieldProps("categoria")}
              /> {formik.errors && <DisplayErrors msgError={formik.errors.categoria}/>}
          </FormGroup>
          <Button type="submit" className="btn-form-voltar" to="/" tag={Link}>Voltar</Button>
          <Button type="submit" className="btn-form-salvar">Salvar</Button>
          </Form>
    </div>
  </Container>   
  );

};

export default FormEditar;
```

[image: Meu formulário de edição i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi do seu exemplo, a API recebe os dados de "initialValues", mas, os dados que seriam atualizados ficariam no state. Eu vejo um problema na atualização do state, já que você grava todas as variáveis do state com o mesmo valor.

Eu tenho um exemplo que atualiza o state, mas não utiliza hooks, este é um exemplo de formulário de cadastro. Acho que vai servir de exemplo para você ajustar o seu código.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { Creators as EnderecoActions } from "../../store/ducks/endereco";

class Endereco extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    enderecoAdicionarRequest: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  state = {
    tipo: "",
    endereco_novo: "",
    numero: "",
    complemento: "",
    bairro: "",
    cidade: "",
    estado: "",
    cep: "",
  };
  componentDidMount(){
    document.title = "Endereço";
    const { enderecoTipoRequest } = this.props;
    enderecoTipoRequest();
  }
  salvar = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const {  tipo, endereco_novo, numero, complemento, bairro, cidade, estado, cep} = this.state;
    const { enderecoAdicionarRequest} = this.props;
    let continuar = true;
    let mensagem = "";

    if (tipo === "" || endereco_novo === "" || numero === "" || bairro === "" || cidade === "" || estado === "" || cep === ""){
      alert("Por favor preencha todos os dados do endereço");
      continuar = false;
    } 
    if (continuar) {
      const dados = {
        codigo_usuario: localStorage.getItem("@SISTEMA:usuario"),
        tipo: tipo,
        rua: rua,
        numero: numero,
        compl: complemento,
        bairro: bairro,
        cidade: cidade,
        estado: estado,
        cep: cep,
      }
      enderecoAdicionarRequest(dados);
      this.props.fechar();
    } else {
      alert(mensagem);
    }
  };

  alterar = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  
  render() {
    const { endereco } = this.props;
    const cep = this.props.endereco.cep;
    return (
      <section id="content">
        <div className="container clearfix">
          <h3>Adicionar Endereço</h3>
          <form onSubmit={this.salvar}>
            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Tipo de Endereco</label>
                <select name="tipo" id="tipo" className="form-control"  onChange={this.alterar}>
                  <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                  {endereco.tipo.map(item => (
                    <option key={item.codigo} value={item.codigo}>{item.titulo}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>CEP</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="cep"
                  placeholder={"00000000"}
                  name="cep"
                  onChange={this.alterar}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Endereço</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="endereco_novo"
                  placeholder="Rua X"
                  name="endereco_novo"
                  onChange={this.alterar}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Número</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="numero"
                  placeholder={"00"}
                  name="numero"
                  onChange={this.alterar}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Complemento</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="complemento"
                  placeholder="Apto, casa"
                  name="complemento"
                  onChange={this.alterar}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Bairro</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="bairro"
                  placeholder="Bairro Y"
                  name="bairro"
                  onChange={this.alterar}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-row">
              <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Cidade</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="cidade"
                  placeholder="Apto, casa"
                  name="cidade"
                  onChange={this.alterar}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Estado</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="estado"
                  placeholder="Sigla"
                  name="estado"
                  onChange={this.alterar}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Salvar
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  endereco: state.endereco
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(EnderecoActions, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Endereco);
```

Como ele só atualiza a sessão se o campo for alterado, para o caso de editar um registro existente, você poderia guardar no state os dados atuais na hora de criar o componente.